# Excluding items from a list that exist in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list for example `List<string> ListProviderKeys` that has some values in it.
I also have a second list from a class below, for example `List<ChangesSummary> SecondList;`

```
public class ChangesSummary
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public string ProviderAdrsKey { get; set; }
    public string ProviderSpecialtyKey { get; set; }
    public string FieldName{ get; set; }
}
```

Imagine the values that first list holds is the same kind of values we put in `ProviderKey`  field in the second list.
Now What I want is to trim down the second list to only have values that their `ProviderKey`  **IS NOT** already in the first list.
How Can I do that? I know the operator Except but not sure how to apply it in this situation!

Comment: there is operator `Exclude`. Try to use it

Comment: to use the Except both list must be of the same value, so you need to convert the type of one of the to the other one to work to apply the except based on your criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is :

A) Create dictionary and use its fast lookups

B) Use LINQ `.Where` method  with `.ContainsKey()` on this dictionary which internally uses `Hashtable` and performs quick lookups.

This should reduce search complexity to almost `O(1)` rather than `O(N)` ro worse (when we use LINQ `.Where()` with `.Any()` or `.Contains()` and that leads to nested loops).

From [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) :

> The Dictionary generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to
>   a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value
>   and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very
>   fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary class is implemented as a
>   hash table.

So what we can do is :

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = ListProviderKeys.ToDictionary(s => s);

var newList = SecondList.Where(e => !dict.ContainsKey(e.ProviderKey)).ToList();
```

Here is a very simple, short, but complete example illustrating it and also testing its performance :

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();
        List<Person> People = new List<Person>(1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7500; i++)
        {
            ints.Add(i);
            ints.Add(15000 - i - 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 45000; i++)
            People.Add(new Person() { Id = i });

        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

        s.Start();

        // code A (feel free to uncomment it)         
        //Dictionary<int, int> dict = ints.ToDictionary(p => p);

        //List<Person> newList = People.Where(p => !dict.ContainsKey(p.Id)).ToList();

        // code B
        List<Person> newList = People.Where(p => !ints.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();

        s.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of elements " + newList.Count);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

On *release* mode results are :

Both code A & code B outputs 30 000 elements but :

It took more than 2000 ms with code B and only 5 ms with code A

Comment: makes sense, but it crashed with my example that I ran.

Comment: List<string> firstList = new List<string>();
            firstList.Add("fdsfd");
            firstList.Add("sdfvf");
            firstList.Add("P2");
            firstList.Add("P4");

Comment: @Bohn i provided short example

Comment: yeah, worked now, thanks. I had copy paste issues in my own example variable names :)

Comment: I sholud just update it a bit to make the string comparison to case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Programm
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             List<ChangesSummary>  summaries = new List<ChangesSummary>();

             summaries.Add(new ChangesSummary()
             {
                 FieldName = "1",
                 ProviderKey = "Test1",
             });

             summaries.Add(new ChangesSummary()
             {
                 FieldName = "2",
                 ProviderKey = "Test2",
             });

             summaries.Add(new ChangesSummary()
             {
                 FieldName = "3",
                 ProviderKey = "Test3",
             });

            List<string> listProviderKeys = new List<string>();

            listProviderKeys.Add("Test1");
            listProviderKeys.Add("Test3");

            var res = summaries.Where(x => !listProviderKeys.Contains(x.ProviderKey));


            res.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ProviderKey));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ChangesSummary
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
        public string ProviderAdrsKey { get; set; }
        public string ProviderSpecialtyKey { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: did you run the example? which is your input data?

Comment: sorry, should work , I had copy paste error in my own example that I was using these codes on .

Answer (score -1):

I think in this case simple `Where` would be easier and more readable to apply.

```
var first = new List<string> { "a" };
var second = new List<ChangesSummary>()
{
    new ChangesSummary() { ProviderKey = "a" },
    new ChangesSummary() { ProviderKey = "b" }
};

var result = second.Where(item => !first.Contains(item.ProviderKey));

// result
//    .ToList()
//    .ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.ProviderKey));
```

Comment: sorry, should work , I had copy paste error in my own example that I was using these codes on

Answer (score -2):

I believe this will work:

```
List<ChangesSummary> ExceptionList = SecondList.
Where(x => !ListProviderKeys.Any(key => x.ProviderKey == key)).ToList();
```